# REGEXP_REPLACE Insert a character after each alpha-numeric group

Tags: oracle, teradata

Let's say I have a string 'ABCSOSLOL', and I'm trying to get it to become 'ABC,SOS,LOL,'

I have been able to accomplish this via this call

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABCSOSLOL',([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]])([[:alpha:]]),'\1\2\3,',1,0);
```

However, this doesn't work if the string becomes 'AB1SOSLO9' - since now it has to be alphanumeric.

Changing :alpha: to [a-z0-9] does not inject a comma. Is there an alphanumeric substitute for :alpha: or a better method?

Trying this in Teradata, and Oracle.

Comment: What if there are some non-alphanumeric characters mixed inbetween, e.g. `'AB1S?SLO9'`?

Comment: @dnoeth, it will then be: 
REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC12!XY4', 
'([[:punct:][:alnum:]]{3})'
, '\1,')

Comment: Do you want to group any three characters? `REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC12!XY4', '(.{3})' , '\1,')` To skip over the final comma: `'(.{3}(?!$))'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Oracle you can use:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123XY4', '([[:alnum:]]{3})', '\1,') FROM DUAL
```

or:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123XY4', '([a-zA-Z0-9]{3})', '\1,') FROM DUAL
```

Which output:

| REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123XY4','([[:ALNUM:]]{3})','\1,') |
| --- |
| ABC,123,XY4, |

If you want to get rid of the trailing comma then you can use `RTRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE('ABC123XY4', '([[:alnum:]]{3})', '\1,'), ',')`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/f7YKFH62)

Comment: beautifully done, alnum (and rtrim) worked in Teradata for me, thank you, so elegant.